# CSS: Skip underline in part of link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, underline

Is it possible to have a contiguous link, where the text is normally underlined on mouse hover, but in the middle have a section (eg an image) without this underline? This does not work:

```
<a href="#">one <span style="text-decoration:none;">two</span> <img src="img.png" style="border:0px; text-decoration:none;"> three</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I really wanted was to have an image "attached" to links, without it getting underlined on hover. Here is a solution I came up with:

```
<a href="#" style="background:url('pic.png') no-repeat; background-position: left center; padding-left: 20px;">Link</a>
```

- *padding-left* is for offsetting the text so it does not overlap the
  image.
- With *background-position* you
  can move the image to make it better
  aligned with the text.
- If the image
  is higher than the text *padding-top*
  and *padding-bottom* can be used to
  tweak the appearance.

This technique can also be used with *CSS sprites* like this:

```
<a href="#" style="background:url('sprites.png') no-repeat; background-position: -16px -16px; padding-left: 32px;">Link</a>
```

I used a similar technique to use CSS sprites instead of ordinary inline images:

```
<span style="background:url('sprites.png') no-repeat; background-position: -16px -16px; padding-left: 32px;"></span>
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Wrapping your <a>'s text in a span and then attaching CSS class that uses this background sprite technique worked really well for me.

Answer (score 6):

Make a class that hides underlines, and child class that adds them.

```css
.underline-some {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.underline-some:hover .text {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="underline-some">
  <span class="text">Boyz</span> 
  <span class="text">Men</span>
</a>
```

This example code above only underlines links on hover. For always-underlined links, remove `:hover`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... the point being to remove the underline from the parent <a> element, then reapplying it only to the child elements you wish to be underlined.

Answer (score 3):

```
a, a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a img, a:hover img { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Comment: how can i do if i want underline on three and not on two after hover?

Comment: Styles: a, a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a img, a:hover img, span.two { text-decoration: none !important; border: 0; } and markup: <a href="#">one <span class="two">two</span> <img src="img.png"> three</a>

Comment: Can't get any of these to work. The image is still underlined.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
     <span style="text-decoration:underline;">one</span>  
    two
    <img src="img.png" style="border:0px; text-decoration:none;"> three
</a>
```

I think it can only be possible using javascript as follows.

**LOOK FOLLOWING EXAMPLE**

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <style>
    a{
       text-decoration:none;
     }

    a:hover
     {
       text-decoration:none;
     }

    .sample
     {
        text-decoration:underline;
     }

    .sample_none
     {
        text-decoration:none;
     }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function show_underline(){
        document.getElementById('sample').className= 'sample';
      }

      function hide_underline(){
        document.getElementById('sample').className= 'sample_none';
      }
   </script>
    <a href="#" onmouseover="show_underline();" onmouseout="hide_underline();"> <span id="sample" class="sample_none">two</span>  
    <img src="img.png" style="border:0px;"> three
    </a>


</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I would like to know if it is possible with css and html only

Comment: This will force the underline to be on all the time. And if I make a special class to handle the hovering, it will break up the contiguous link.

Comment: please paste your code after you done it. I would like to know how you handle the hovering. neways Really Good Question :)

Comment: Salil: Upon further testing I discovered that it didnnot solve my problem.

Comment: check my example that uses javascript.

Comment: Your example works, but only for one "text part", since it uses an id to find the text to underline. Also, it seems a bit complex for such a simple thing.